# how to use spark streaming + kafka with streamingListener

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

i have one situation here.

I want that my aplication connect one time to kafka, read the offset, make an action and then stop the application.

I was reading about StreamingListener for detect when the first iteration occurs.

i don´t know how use StreamingListener to stop mi application. can you help me?

I am using spark 1.4

Example code bellow:

```
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)

lines.foreachRDD( rdd => {
  rdd.saveAsTextFile("......")
})


sys.ShutdownHookThread {
  println("Gracefully stopping Spark Streaming Application")
  ssc.stop(true, true)
  println("Application stopped")
}

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

thanks!

Comment: If you only read it once, why use Spark Streaming?

Comment: can i establish connection with kafka without spark streaming? i have to use spark , no other.

Comment: Use `KafkaRDD` directly from Spark

Comment: i need to read the new msg from kafka, with kafkRDD i have to use Offsets, is any way to stop spark completely after the first iteration?